# How to graphically add two functions

Tags: graphing-functions

I have tried looking for tutorials or guides online, but I keep finding problems that are fairly similar but not exactly what I am looking for. I know how to add functions regularly, I am familiar with graphing an equation using its slope and $y$-intercept, etc., but I have no idea where to begin on finding the sum of two functions using this graph:

> $$\mathrm{Use\ the \ graph \ to \ find \ }f(0)+g(0).$$
>   [image]

Comment: The graph of $f$ crosses the origin when $x=0$.  This means that $f(0)=0$.  Do the same process with $g$ to get $g(0)$.  Then subtract the two.

Comment: Are you able to separately evaluate $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ from the given graphs?

Answer (score 1):

Add the $y-$ values of each of the points, while keeping the $x-$values the same to get the new point for the function $(f+g)(x)$.

One thing I did not see mentioned is that the domains do not coincide. The function $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ can not exist where one of them does not. The domain of the function $(f+g)(x)$ is the intersection of the two domains (or "overlap"), and domain of $f$ and $g$ intersect on $D_f\cap D_g = [-4,3]$

Comment: g contains 9 y-values and f contains 8 y-values. What am I supposed to do with the extra y-value? Or am I supposed to only count y-values within certain bounds?

Comment: It will only exist from $-4$ to $3$

Comment: Ah I see. So I have my new line but I am still not sure what then the sum is

Comment: as others said first you have to find the parts in which both functions exist which is [-4,3] and then you have to add the values of each function and put the new point on the graph. for g(0) and f(0) it is (0-2)=-2 and also you have to do this for each point and graph whole function of h(x)=f(x)+g(x)